# What is the difference between udp(4) and udp(6)?

Tags: node.js, udp

Can somebody go over the syntax differences and possible use case differences between udp(4) and udp(6)?

[I noticed there is a difference marked in the Node documentation when creating a datagram socket.](http://nodejs.org/api/dgram.html#dgram_udp_datagram_sockets)

Comment: IPv4 / IPv6, no?

Comment: Are there any performance differences or tradeoffs?

Answer (score 8):

The only difference is as Mat mentioned that udp6 uses IPv6 and udp4 uses IPv4. The `type` parameter you specify when creating a socket indicates which interface will be used. The rest of the API is the same.